# xamarin UTF8Encoding string to NSURL

Tags: utf-8, xamarin, nsurl

i need to open a Webview that translate some word from chinese to English , i am doing like this

```
string urlString = "https://translate.google.com.tw/#zh-CN/en/中文測試";
NSUrl url = new NSUrl(urlString);

NSUrlRequest request = new NSUrlRequest(url);
WebViewController transView = new WebViewController(request);
```

it should open the url https://translate.google.com.tw/#zh-CN/en/中文 , but will show "the native 'initWithString:'" method returned nil , i think i should doing some encode to my urlString.

i try to change my code like this

```
string urlString = "https://translate.google.com.tw/#zh-CN/en/";
urlString = urlString + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("中文測試",Encoding.UTF8);
NSUrl url = new NSUrl(urlString);
NSUrlRequest request = new NSUrlRequest(url);
WebViewController transView = new WebViewController(request);
```

but the WebView only open "https://translate.google.com.tw/#zh-CN/en/" , my encoding part not handled.

Comment: And have you tried encoding the urlString, since this is what you suggest?

Comment: yeah , but the issue not solved , not sure what part was wrong.